# Differences in variables

Tags: php, uppercase, lowercase

Is `$abc` equal to `$Abc` in variables? I found two sites about `lua` and some programming language I don't understand. Others goes about posts on S.O. but about arrays in PHP. Anothers on other website goes about making strings uppercase or lowercase.

My real question is `echo $Abc;` equal to `echo $abc;`?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: What does echo $Abc === $abc do?

Comment: RTFM? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php Relevant: 2nd sentence on the page

Comment: That was fastest 2 downvotes ever! Keep on!

Comment: @RikTelner What did you expect? You show no effort in solving this so very simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

```
<?php
$var = 'Bob';
$Var = 'Joe';
echo "$var, $Var";      // outputs "Bob, Joe"
?>
```

So from this example `$var` was not overwitten by `$Var`.

**So to answer your question `$abc` is not equal to `$Abc`**

Answer (score 5):

PHP variable names are [case sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), so `$abc` is different from `$Abc`